List Formatting using multiple icons as buttons to set Value of [$Status]
I have a list I use as a Visitor Register in SharePoint. I use the list to keep track of hundreds of visitors. This is managed via the 'status' column (Appointment, Check-In, Overdue, Check-Out).
I am able to create one button per column that changes the value of the 'status' column from the normal view (not datasheet view), but I want to be able to use one column to set the value all the status options, using Icons, as pictured below.
The Visitor Register list already contains up to 20 columns of data so I want to streamline actions on a single click.
The code in the Action column (pictured) is sourced from GitHub. which I modified using the attached.
I have tried to add in setValue actions in the code but have failed thus far.  Suggestions would be greatly appreciated if this action can be made workable.
{
 "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
 "elmType": "div",
 "style": {
   "font-size": "16px"
 },
 "children": [
   {
     "elmType": "span",
     "attributes": {
       "title": "Appointment",
       "iconName": "Notepinned",
       "class": "='ms-fontColor-' 'themeDark', 'neutral')"
     },
     "style": {
       "padding": "0 6px"
     }
   },
   {
     "elmType": "span",
     "attributes": {
       "title": "Check-in",
       "iconName": "Pinnedsolid",
       "class": "='ms-fontColor-''themeDark', 'neutral')"
     },
     "style": {
       "padding": "0 4px 0 0"
     }
   },
   {
     "elmType": "span",
     "attributes": {
       "title": "Overdue",
       "iconName": "Alarmclock",
       "class": "='ms-fontColor-' 'themeDark', 'neutral')"
     },
     "style": {
       "padding": "0 4px"
     }
   },
   {
     "elmType": "span",
     "attributes": {
       "title": "Check-out",
       "iconName": "unpin",
       "class": "='ms-fontColor-' 'themeDark', 'neutral')"
     },
     "style": {
       "padding": "0 4px"
     }
   },
   {
     "elmType": "span",
     "attributes": {
       "title": "",
       "iconName": "",
       "class": "='ms-fontColor-'  'themeDark', 'neutral')"
     },
     "style": {
       "padding": "0 4px"
     }
   }
 ]
}


